# Why does my page reload automatically?

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever I click on "add JavaScript", the action programmed is executed, but the page reloads. I just want to add a link on a div and show it on screen.
Someone knows why?

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var adicionar = document.getElementById("adicionar");
  adicionar.onclick = function(){
   add(); 
  }
};
function add(){ 
    var div      = document.getElementById("link-meio");
    var novoLink = document.createElement('A');
    var novoTexto = document.createTextNode("Novo textoooo");
    novoLink.appendChild(novoTexto);
    div.appendChild(novoLink);

}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul !!! problem solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#adicionar` must be an anchor tag. You can `return false` from your click handler to disable the default behaviour of the click on an anchor tag (which is to load the page corresponding to the `href` attribute, and will cause the current page to reload if the `href` is empty).

Comment: In HTML is   <div id="link-fim">
    <a href="" id="adicionar">Add JavaScript</a>
          </div>

Answer (score 0):

Its is caused by the default event is triggered when you do click on the a element with id "adicionar", you could call the preventDefault method before, like this

```
window.onload = function(){
  var adicionar = document.getElementById("adicionar");
  adicionar.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    add();  
  }
};
function add(){ 
    var div      = document.getElementById("link-meio");
    var novoLink = document.createElement('A');
    var novoTexto = document.createTextNode("Novo textoooo");
    novoLink.appendChild(novoTexto);
    div.appendChild(novoLink);

}
```